# Как правильно вывести js в отдельный файл и сделать на него ссылку в html?

Tags: javascript

Вставил в HTML скрипт, делающий плавный скролл на странице.

Каким образом можно его спрятать в отдельный файл js, а в html сделать ссылку на этот файл?

Вот скрипт:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 250, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаешь отдельный js файл и в html прописываешь `<script src="путь к файлу"></script>`

Comment: Делаю так, не работает...

Comment: Вот такой пут прописываю: <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/smoothscroll.js"></script>

Comment: Проверь пути, попробуй `src="./js/smoothscroll.js"`

Comment: А где у тебя находится js файл относительно файла к которому ты его подключаешь?

Comment: Такой вариант тоже не получается <script type = "text/javascript" src = "./js/smoothscroll.js"></script>

Comment: И с двумя точками тоже. Там jquery используется. Может, из-за него не срабатывает? Главное, если на html страницу вставить, все работает.

Comment: У меня вот такое дерево: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uSoUG_Beq8bVecw1tcPvoGPRRaDnOGpS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Скрипт нужен в файле index

Comment: @Nikita Migushev ок, а в каком месте файла ты его подключаешь? Там же где у тебя был скрипт? Что откроется, если открыть инструменты разработчика и перейти по ссылке из атрибута src?

Comment: Да, в том же месте https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oADF3xKUfojb6dVlrOIMrnrzYbU9aq69/view?usp=sharing

Comment: В панели разработчика вижу вот это https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DlVKpIJfzLwqLxcfLSFaA5jO4NaNPi_z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: А как перейти по ссылке из атрибута src в панели разработчика?

Comment: А почему у тебя в изначальном примере кода перед скриптом подключается jquery, а на скрине нормалайз css если подключаешь там же?

Comment: Подключается всё правильно. Проблема в отсутствии jquery

Comment: Добавил библиотеку jquery, все равно не работает

Comment: Вот папка с проектом. Есть возможность глянуть, что там не так? https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WfjhANGo0ecmJ5_vn_duQeTyefXw_5-r?usp=sharing

Comment: Я там не вижу jquery

Comment: Перед подключением своего скрипта добавь подключение jquery и всё заработает. он должен подключатся перед всеми скриптами которые требуют его для работы

Comment: Вау, ты маг и волшебник! Заработало )